# Enabling Reset Password and email verification for parse-server hosted locally

Tags: parse-server

I am trying to enable reset password and email verification for my parse-server-example installed locally. I could see we have https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-mailgun.

But I am not clear how to use parse-mailgun in parse-server-example, I am completely lost with it.
Can somebody explain or suggest steps to enable it?

Regards
Atul

Comment: Hi I could resolve it, and below the the way you could achieve it:

Answer (score 13):

1. Create account with MailGun, and get apiKey and Domain from its website.
2. Copy and Paste below configuration under index.js file of your parse-server-example git folder at your local system.You can get this file under parse-server-example folder directly.

---

```
verifyUserEmails: true,
publicServerURL: 'https://yourproject.herokuapp.com/parse',
appName: 'Parse App',
emailAdapter: { 
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: { 
               fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
               domain: '<domainProvidedFromMailGun>.mailgun.org', 
               apiKey: 'key-FromMailGun', 
             }
 },
```

---

Push it to heroku app git, since I have piloted my parse-server to heroku so below cmd's will be valid.

```
git add .
git commit -m "mypush commit"
heroku git:remote -a fast-springs-29785
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Email verification and password reset

Verifying user email addresses and enabling password reset via email requries an email adapter. As part of the parse-server package we provide an adapter for sending email through Mailgun. To use it, sign up for Mailgun, and add this to your initialization code:

```
var server = ParseServer({
  ...otherOptions,
  // Enable email verification
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  // The public URL of your app.
  // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
  // Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
  publicServerURL: 'https://example.com/parse',
  // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
  appName: 'Parse App',
  // The email adapter
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'example.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-mykey',
    }
  }
});
```

You can also use other email adapters contributed by the community such as parse-server-sendgrid-adapter or parse-server-mandrill-adapter.