# Bitnami Parse Server install is incomplete on Amazon Web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, bitnami

1. I've launched a new EC2 instance, **Parse Server powered by Bitnami (HVM)**

[image]

2. After installation, The "**Analytics**" and "**App Settings**" are missing.
3. Also, there is **no login screen**. Anyone who has the IP address can just access the console and change everything.

[image]

What have I done wrong? It is a new App, so I don't have the need to migrate an old Parse DB.

Comment: Do you have a solution yet? I have the same issue and not sure how I can fix it.

Comment: I cannot see app settings and I need that to configure password reset emails. I have already completed adding push and steps listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764372/enabling-reset-password-and-email-verification-for-parse-server-hosted-locally If you find anything please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here.

1. Either setup a server side password protection from apache side check this guide. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04
2. Second option is in security group for your EC2 instance for just set this below rule so only you can check the dashboard from your local machine with your IP address also make sure HTTP is not having a rule 0.0.0.0/32 in the security group.

[image]

For setting Analytics and App Setting check this guide https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Parse_Server