# Index.js file continuously gives "JSON text did not start with array" despite being formatted as an array

Tags: json, heroku, parse-server, mailgun

I have a parse-server hosted by heroku, which has an `index.js` file utilized for its configuration. I want to use Mailgun to up functionality for the user to request a password reset, and I have set up the config file, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764372/enabling-reset-password-and-email-verification-for-parse-server-hosted-locally), as follows:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  appName: 'App Name',
  publicServerURL: 'https://<name>.herokuapp.com/parse',
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it $
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't$
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query s$
  },
  push: JSON.parse(process.env.SERVER_PUSH || "{}"),
  verifyUserEmails: true, //causing errors
  emailAdapter: { //causing errors
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: { 
             fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
             domain: '<domain>', 
             apiKey: '<key>', 
           }
  }
});
```

This code does not work, though, because of the `verifyUserEmails` and `emailAdapter`. Removing both of them removes the "JSON text did not start with array" error. Adding either one of them back in results in the error being thrown. I have no idea why, though, since I do not see any obvious reason as to how they aren't being set up in an array correctly?
Do I need to set up the cooresponding config vars in heroku in addition to having them in the config file? I considered this, but `appName` and `publicServerURL` are not set up in this way and don't give this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is repeatedly running into this issue, I have figured out exactly what was going wrong. Despite the error informing me that my JSON was incorrectly formatted, it turns out it was actually that the `module` was misnamed.  According to [this post](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4535), the updated module has been renamed to `'@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter'`. Inserting this into the `index.js`, after ensuring I had ran the `npm install --save @parse/simple-mailgun-adapter` in my local repo, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

emailAdapter.options.apiKey doesn't need a comma at the end since its the last element of it's JSON.

I wouldn't be surprised that you're also leaving in the comma at the end of verifyUserEmails when you include it improperly as well.

```
options: { 
             fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
             domain: '<domain>', 
             apiKey: '<key>', 
           }
```

This is not valid JSON, because there is a comma at the end of the apiKey line. The last item in a JSON object does not have a comma.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean that I am including the comma at the end of verifyUserEmails improperly?

Comment: Edited my answer to be more explicit.