# Error: An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset and email verification functionality

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server, pfuser, parse-ios-sdk

I have an iOS mobile app written in Swift. I am using Parse Server as my backend and I am trying to implement password reset. The documentation only suggests adding the code below which I have done.

`PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground("email@example.com")`

However, I get the error **An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset and email verification functionality**. I have found a lot of material on implementing Mailgun with parse to make this work but they are all in Javascript. Do I have to implement Mailgun in Swift? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling Reset Password and email verification for parse-server hosted locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764372/enabling-reset-password-and-email-verification-for-parse-server-hosted-locally)

Comment: If it has solved your issue, it would be helpful if you could accept my answer. If not, let me know and I will try to help further.

Comment: Hey @TomFox and Jayyunit, if you can solved this problem, can you share solution.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to implement Mailgun in Swift the `requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackGround()` is all you need on the client side.

The examples you have found are in JavaScript because you need to configure password reset in your Parse Server initialisation as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Server#email-verification-and-password-reset):

```js
var server = ParseServer({
  ...otherOptions,
  // Enable email verification
  verifyUserEmails: true,

  // if `verifyUserEmails` is `true` and
  //     if `emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration` is `undefined` then
  //        email verify token never expires
  //     else
  //        email verify token expires after `emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration`
  //
  // `emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration` defaults to `undefined`
  //
  // email verify token below expires in 2 hours (= 2 * 60 * 60 == 7200 seconds)
  emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60, // in seconds (2 hours = 7200 seconds)

  // set preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail to false to allow user to login without verifying their email
  // set preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail to true to prevent user from login if their email is not verified
  preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false, // defaults to false

  // The public URL of your app.
  // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
  // Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
  publicServerURL: 'https://example.com/parse',
  // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
  appName: 'Parse App',
  // The email adapter
  emailAdapter: {
    module: '@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'example.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-mykey',
    }
  },

  // account lockout policy setting (OPTIONAL) - defaults to undefined
  // if the account lockout policy is set and there are more than `threshold` number of failed login attempts then the `login` api call returns error code `Parse.Error.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND` with error message `Your account is locked due to multiple failed login attempts. Please try again after <duration> minute(s)`. After `duration` minutes of no login attempts, the application will allow the user to try login again.
  accountLockout: {
    duration: 5, // duration policy setting determines the number of minutes that a locked-out account remains locked out before automatically becoming unlocked. Set it to a value greater than 0 and less than 100000.
    threshold: 3, // threshold policy setting determines the number of failed sign-in attempts that will cause a user account to be locked. Set it to an integer value greater than 0 and less than 1000.
  },
  // optional settings to enforce password policies
  passwordPolicy: {
    // Two optional settings to enforce strong passwords. Either one or both can be specified. 
    // If both are specified, both checks must pass to accept the password
    // 1. a RegExp object or a regex string representing the pattern to enforce 
    validatorPattern: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/, // enforce password with at least 8 char with at least 1 lower case, 1 upper case and 1 digit
    // 2. a callback function to be invoked to validate the password
    validatorCallback: (password) => { return validatePassword(password) }, 
    validationError: 'Password must contain at least 1 digit.' // optional error message to be sent instead of the default "Password does not meet the Password Policy requirements." message.
    doNotAllowUsername: true, // optional setting to disallow username in passwords
    maxPasswordAge: 90, // optional setting in days for password expiry. Login fails if user does not reset the password within this period after signup/last reset. 
    maxPasswordHistory: 5, // optional setting to prevent reuse of previous n passwords. Maximum value that can be specified is 20. Not specifying it or specifying 0 will not enforce history.
    //optional setting to set a validity duration for password reset links (in seconds)
    resetTokenValidityDuration: 24*60*60, // expire after 24 hours
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I implement on iOS with swift?