# Email verification failing

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server, mailgun

I have installed Parse Server directly from [Heroku and mLab button](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) and then [Deploy to Heroku Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku).

This is working fine, but now I need to set up email verification. I have installed Mailgun and Mailgun Email Verification addons directly from Heroku. Under `Config vars` the correct keys are all there, but I get the error

> An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for
>   password reset and email verification functionality. (Code: 1,
>   Version: 1.17.2)

I was under the impression that when installing addons directly from Heroku, the settings was deployed automatically. Do I need to configure anything else after installing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling Reset Password and email verification for parse-server hosted locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764372/enabling-reset-password-and-email-verification-for-parse-server-hosted-locally)

Answer (score 0):

That message isn't from Mailgun; it's [from the parse server itself](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/search?q=are+required+for+password+reset&unscoped_q=are+required+for+password+reset).

You'll have to either customize the code or [configure it properly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku#configuring-your-parse-server-with-config-vars). I don't think the example code gives you a way to configure `appName`, `publicServerUrl`, or `emailAdapter` from the environment so you'll probably have to deploy a customized instance that [sets those variables](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#configuration). [This example](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#email-verification-and-password-reset) looks helpful.